# How to push a document in an array nested in another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, crud

This is my problem : I have a document ( let's call it root) containing an array of another documents (stick), that contain another array of another documents (leaf).

Or simply said : root{ stickChain[leaveschain1[ leaf1, leaf2],leaveschain2[ leaf1, leaf2] ]}

I have access to root _id, stick _id, or whatever it is needed to identify each document.

Basically, the best result I've come so far is, when creating my leaves documents, is to store then at the same level tha sticks, or in another word I've come to create an array of leaves in root.

I'm working in javascript and using mongoose

This is the line I've used:

```
db.collection('root').findOneAndUpdate({ _id: root.id, "stick._id":expTemp._id },{stickChain:{$push: {"leavechain.$": leaf}}})
```

And I this gives me this result : root{ leavesChain[leaf1,leaf2], stickchain[1,2,3] }

[I've come across something new to me](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#definition) (since Mongodb 3.6 there is a new way of handling array of arrays), here is what I've tried :

```
  try{  db.collection('root').findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: root.id, "stick._id":expTemp._id },
        {$push: {"stickChain.$[xpc].leavesChain.$[qac]": leaf}},
        { arrayFilters: [ { "xpc._id": user._id } , { "qac._id": expTemp._id } ]})}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 try{  db.collection('root').findAndModify(

        {$push: {"root.$[cv].stickChain.$[xpc].leavesChain.$[qac]": leaf}},
        { arrayFilters: [ {"cv._id":user.cv} ,{ "xpc._id": user._id } , { "qac._id": expTemp._id } ],
        upsert:true})
        .catch(error => console.error(error))

    }catch{}
```

And this gives me a new kind of error : *MongoError: Either an update or remove=true must be specified*

The thing is that I'm not familiar with how to do it, while I know what I want to do: I want to insert a "leaf" into a specific array in a document fetched in MongoDB. Maybe not the best practice, so any hint are welcome :)

Comment: I just posted an answer to another question like this. You should **not** put arrays into arrays inside a document. It's better to use another model. You'll have issues with querying and updating, not to mention it's extremely not optimized. Good luck!

Comment: All right, then I sould go wth something like : _root[stickChain _id]_ and then _stick[leavesChain[leaf]]_ ? I mean extract a level of "nestedeness" ? How is that optimized ? I'm genuinelly courious on how it works, and if you could brievely explain it I could avoid such bad practices from now on :)

Comment: The thing is that if you try to search for something, the adapter would traverse all documents, then all first level documents, then all second level documents. That's basically everything you've got. If you just split them, then you'd skip a level of traversing, which is extremely important. Also there's no possibility to do that fully simultaneously (just partially). I mean you get a single document, then you start searching its 1st lvl subdocs. Then for each subdoc, you get all sub-sub-docs. Nothing is found, so you go back to the second document in the collection...

Comment: If you get that many levels of nesting, you'd typically split them into separate collections and use references. It's a bit more like traditional relational database, but as fewer connections as possible. Then you index the second table by id, meaning that when you get a document, you could say "give me the list of tasks for that document, the list is with id 5". It's very fast because of the index, and therefore you skip the whole traversing over again. It's like a tree, and the more arrays you have, the more branches there are. Document should be as flat as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Here's a good read I just found, it basically sums up what I said but in a better way: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've splitted my dument like this :

- root[stickChain _id]
- stick[leavesChain[leaf]]

Thanks to Andrey Popov for his explications